# angular 7 application is not working when refreshed at route level after hosting in azure

Tags: azure, deployment, angular7

In our team we have developed an angular7 application and hosted in azure. the website is working fine with or without refresh when the url is like http://xyz.azurewebsites.net/. I can traverse pages by clicking on the links without any problem. For example, it is possible to traverse pages like http://xyz.azurewebsites.net/page1, but this time when I refresh/press ctrl f5 in the browser it is showing: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I googled and tried some work around as below:

1. Created a web.config file for url rewrite and placed it in the src folder of the angular application, added web.config in the

"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],

inside angular.json file but ended in vein.

2. Created a web.config file for url rewrite and placed it in the root of the angular application, added web.config in the

"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "web.config"
            ],

inside angular.json file but ended in vein.

3. Tried placing/without placing web.config in the dist (after creating the dist using ng build --prod command) folder but ended in vein.
4. Tried with two different contents in web.config as below:

   First:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
           <staticContent>
               <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
               <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
               <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
           </staticContent>
       </system.webServer>
       <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url=".*" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                       </conditions>
                       <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                   </rule>
               </rules>
           </rewrite>
         </system.webServer>
       </configuration>
   ```

   and second:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
           <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url=".*" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
           </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

But ended in vein.

in my case `<base href="/">` in the index.html in both the dist and src folder of the angular application.
What else can be tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with azure and how to configure it. But the problem is that your webserver is not serving your index.html in your subroutes. You have to tell your Webserver to serve the index.html in your root folder (xyz.azurewebsites.net) to also serve that index.html when in any subroutes ("xyz.azurewebsites.net/subroute" or "xyz.azurewebsites.net/some/depper/subroute")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally worked, I just put web.config inside src folder and wrote path of that file in the angular.json as below:

```
"assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/web.config" ]
```

And then committed in azure. Though I did the same earlier but it worked at last !!!

Thanks

Comment: Note: my existing version of angular.json already had "assets" and the first 2 fields.  I only had to add "src/web.config".

Comment: +1 This solution worked for me and overboard182’s Kudu services console debugging tip was a great help as well

Comment: Worked here so well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

the issue might be that the web.config should be at the root of wwwroot folder not inside the source of the angular app. you can validate this with advanced tools when viewing your app service resource. hit go from advanced tools and that will route you to Kudu services. you can use the debug console to see all your files.

An alternative is to put your angular /dist contents in a storage account and use an azure function proxy to handle the redirects.  If thats that works for your requirements there is more information here: https://markheath.net/post/static-websites-azure-blob-storage-functions-proxies